# Is there anything special about fugu meat?

Tags: food-safety, fish, japanese-cuisine

I know that fugu is fairly well known both inside and outside Japan, and wild versions of the fish contains a toxin [1200 times more potent](http://press.fourseasons.com/doha/hotel-news/fugu-tasting-menu-at-nusantao-sea-kitchens-brings-extreme-dining-to-four-seasons-hotel-doha/) than cyanide. (Fun fact: one species is also the [second vertebrate to have its genome sequenced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takifugu_rubripes) after humans)

What I don't know is whether the fish is famous (and considered a "delicacy") solely because of its potential toxicity, or whether there is something else unique about its meat.

Is there anything unique about fugu meat, such as its flavour or texture?

Comment: @hippietrail I think "food-unsafety" would be a better tag than "food-safety"!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to an article about Fugu at [Maldova Welcome](http://www.welcome-moldova.com/articles/fugu.shtml):

> Some people who’ve tried puffer dishes describe it as one of the most
>   sublime flavors in the world. Others, apparently less enthusiastic, or
>   simply more objective, describe fugu meat as a cross between crunchy
>   and chewy, said by the Japanese to go “shiko-shiko” in one’s mouth
>   when absolutely fresh. That’s what some consider the main attraction
>   of the risky meal. But taste isn’t everything. Many say that fugu is
>   simply addictive!

According to [YQ Travelling](http://yqtravelling.com/2012/03/03/what-does-fugu-tastes-like/):  "Long answer: like rubber when raw but like silk when cooked."

At [New York Food](http://nymag.com/restaurants/features/46462/index2.html) (in an indepth article), Adam Platt says:

> Hashimoto’s fugu indeed has a certain clean sashimi quality to it, and
>   a resilient chewiness, but otherwise it’s a letdown. It tastes
>   flavorless and gummy, like a cross between Reichl’s fluke and day-old
>   squid.
>
> [ ... ]
>   And then the tingling sensation begins. It starts on my lips and seems to be quickly tracking 
>   down the back of my throat. I put down my chopsticks and shift my legs
>   under the table. I bring the tips of my fingers to my mouth and begin
>   touching my lips in a tender, slightly agitated way, like a d
>   dental patient shot full of Novocain.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> our next course, which is a little helping of deep-fried fugu ribs. The bony ribs (“These look 
>   like hamster ribs,” I tell Shinji) are hacked in little pieces, tossed
>   in flour, and seasoned with sea salt and a sprinkling of the dried
>   kelp called kombu. The ribs have the nice meaty texture of monkfish,
>   they’re perfectly fried, and they’re delicious. (This may simply prove
>   that anything tastes good fried, including bony, potentially fatal
>   fish ribs.)

However, I suspect the popularity of fugu, especially in Japan is a complex amalgam of factors including:

- Pride in cultural heritage, since this is a uniquely Japanese practice, although it is spreading
- The enjoyment of the feeling of numbness that properly prepared fugu leaves in the mouth, from just the tiniest traces of the toxin
- Popularity of extremely expensive items, which therefore *must* be special
- The art of the presentation, which (as the dish is very expensive) is at its highest levels
- Some people are crazy :-)

Comment: I was waiting for the last one :)

Answer (score 4):

I think fugu is a specialty served in particular regions in Japan, and so it's one of those things that people like to try on 'regional food travels'.

I have tried fugu sashimi several times, and it is served in a way peculiar to fugu only: sliced paper-thin, and with a special vinegar/soy sauce and condiments. The texture and flavour is a bit similar to extremely fresh snapper - ie. pretty flavourless, and firm/crunchy/rubbery in texture.

So, this is mainly my opinion, but I think in terms of flavour, a certain amount of appeal does exist in the unique way that it is eaten as sashimi (and Japanese love travelling to try unique dishes particular to different areas). I also imagine that until relatively recently it would have been rare, expensive and thus exclusive - though nowadays you can even get it at some regional supermarkets - and a sense of it being a desirable gourmet food is still very present.