# Is foreigner-grade VB sold within Australia?

Tags: shopping, beer, australian-cuisine

As a gift, a friend of mine was given a collection of Australiana. It included some iconic Australian foods, some other knick-knacks, and a can of Victoria Bitter. I suspect that they're from a single pre-prepared bag of Australiana.

While I know that VB's advertising is very famous and regarded as very Australian, I've heard rumours that the VB that's sold overseas is inferior to the VB sold in Australia. Is that true? If so, is foreigner-grade VB likely to be sold in collections of Australiana within Australia?

Comment: I wanted to add the tag "Australian-cuisine", but I lacked the reputation.

Comment: VB is not cuisine :-)

Comment: This almost seems like more of a question for [travel.se], if it were reworded from a non-Australian point of view. As it is, I'm not really sure what it has to do with cooking...

Comment: @Aaronut which SE do you think http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34859/is-there-anything-special-about-fugu-meat was more suited to? Travel or cooking? I though travel, but everyone else thought cooking.

Answer (score 1):

Its possibly due to the recent changes the company made to their branding.. which also changed the strength, and the labelling.. its likely your friend received "old ones"..

There was a loutish back-lash against the company, they have since "reverted", and embraced the fact that people LIKE a stronger brew..

still has no fizz though.

http://www.news.com.au/business/aussie-beer-favourite-victoria-bitter-back-to-full-strength/story-e6frfm1i-1226464247134